# Data prep / variable creation for predictive models

Tags: machine-learning, references, data-mining, feature-engineering

I was reading a couple of the write ups from a Kaggle challenge: [Here is one](http://www.kaggle.com/c/dunnhumbychallenge/forums/t/922/2nd-place-methodology/6041#post6041) and [another](http://blog.kaggle.com/2011/10/19/deceitful-beast-william-cukierski/)
and it got me wondering about variable creation in data mining and why there seems to exist so few texts or case studies available.

Are there any example out there besides Dorian Pyle [book?](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1558605290)

I am thinking full case studies of prediction challenges and feature creation / variable deriving and how one should approach it: domain knowledge of course, but also from EDA.

Comment: You might be interested in some of [George Forman](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/George_Forman/Publications.html)'s work. I think it largely focuses on feature selection for text, but some of the ideas are more generally applicable.